# Induction question

Tags: nt.number-theory

Given a set of n+1 numbers from 1,2....,2n . How to prove by induction that there exists two numbers in the set such that one divides the other ???

Comment: Actually, one is twice the other. Here pigeonhole seems better than induction. Consider the n subsets {1,2},{2,4},..,{n,2n}.

Comment: This is a problem for the epsilons :)

Comment: @Pietro: I dont think one has to be twice of the other. In the classical solution one considers the n chains C_k={k,2k,4k,...} for $k\in \{1,3,5,\dots, 2n-1\}$ and then use the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: oops!         .        

Answer (score 3):

Assume we have the statement for 2n, and we are given n+2 numbers up to 2n+2. If n+1 amon them are at most 2n, then we are done by induction. So only n of them can be at most 2n, that is, 2n+1 and 2n+2 are among the numbers. Then n+1 is not among the numbers (as n+1 divides 2n+2). We can now replace 2n+2 by n+1 and still keep the condition. This is a contradiction, as now we have n+1 numbers up to 2n. QED.

Answer (score 0):

As Gjergji points out, I believe this is a problem that Erdos liked to test young children with, and the classical solution uses the pigeonhole principle.  However, I will answer the OP's question, since there is indeed a proof by induction.

Clearly, the claim holds for $n=1$.  Now, assume that it holds for $n-1$, and consider a subset $X$ of size $n+1$ from $[2n]$.  If $X$ contains at least $n$ elements from $[2n-2]$, then we are done by induction.  So, $X$ must contain both $2n-1$ and $2n$.  Now, if $n \in X$, we are done.  So, let $X'$ be obtained from $X$ by removing $2n$ and adding $n$.  By induction, $X'$ contains two numbers one of which divides the other, and hence $X$ does too.

Comment: Wasn't Erdos' problem to prove that two of them are relatively prime?  That one has an instant solution; this appears not to.

Comment: This one has an instant solution too.  Two of the numbers must have the same odd part.  QED.  

Comment: Is there a list (somewhere) of Erdos-type questions for the "epsilons"?